# Hibernate If row exits map to boolean attribute

Tags: hibernate, criteria

I have a hibernate domain class, let say Product and it is mapped to the product table.   I have another table called Order.  Each table has an linkId field and these table can be joined by this field.  In the product class I have a boolean attribute but it is not mapped to any column in the product table.   Is it possible to create a criteria that would join these two tables and populate the boolean field on porduct to true if matching rows exist in the order table and false if no matching rows exist.

I would need an example.
Thanks

Comment: What did you try? Could you post some code? Thanks.

Comment: How about write a getter for the boolean field instead of the criteria. In the getter you just check if there are orders for the product. You may not need a private field of the boolean field in the product class.